# Docker - ERROR: lstat no such file or directory

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I want to deploy a spring boot app using docker in [render](https://render.com/) but I am struggling with `lstat /home/user/.local/tmp/buildkit-mount619141597/target: no such file or directory.`

Se below my docker file:

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17 as maven-builder
COPY src /app/src
COPY pom.xml /app

RUN mvn -f /app/pom.xml clean package -DskipTests
FROM openjdk:17-alpine

RUN "ls"

COPY --from=maven-builder target/*.jar /app-service/godelivery.jar
WORKDIR /app-service

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","godelivery.jar"]
```

[image: Docker error]

Cheers

I've to follow this tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3AIecyvok4 and yet I am unable to deploy the app.

Comment: This 46-star repo shows how to do this with render, might be helpful: https://github.com/TakiRahal/spring-boot-render